# Is it better to have one dynamic page or multiple pages that redirect depending on a dropdown option?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a drop down box with multiple selections, I am going to set it up so that depending on the selection the fields in the form will change.

I have currently thought of two ways to do this (keep in mind I'm relatively new to web development):

- The first method is using one page of HTML with a JS function that will show
  specific fields depending on the sections display value, a la:
  `elem.style.display="inline"` or `elem.style.display="none"`
- The second method is to have multiple pages and to use JS to redirect
  depending on which item is chosen.

Is there a preferred method? Do users prefer a specific method, which one is more efficient? I believe the second would be easier to manage in the future but I wonder about its usability and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the user it is usually nicer to use the first method since there is not the wait of a page load.  There are probably times and places where it is better to use separate pages, but for the most part I would say doing it all on one page is better.

Here is a quick list of some of the pros and cons

First method:
Pros:
1. No extra page loads (however the first page could be slow if you try to load to much)
2. Easier for the user to stay with the flow of the process
3. It looks cooler/trendy when the page responds immediately to input (somewhat subjective I know)
Cons:
1. Can be quite a bit more complicated to maintain
2. Along with one can be a lot easier to introduce bugs

Second method:
Pros:
1. Straightforward to develop
2. Signals to the user there is a change in what you are doing (In some cases switching pages creates logical breaks in the users mind.)
Cons:
1. Can look a little outdated (again its subjective)
2. There is some maintenance on the backend making sure everything gets communicated from one page to the next correctly and securely

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the standard method for changing a page based on a drop down box or some other element is to get javascript to hide/show parts of the page, or otherwise modify the page to suit using DOM methods.

There are many javascript toolkits that take care of most of the messy details of writing javascript code that does tricky things like changing pages, while making sure everything works on all browsers.  Do check one out. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is one of the most popular toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if I understand what you want to achieve, but what I do is build a "controller" type page in PHP that will receive all the posts asynchronously from JavaScript/jQuery.  then the controller page would elicit whatever extra forms it needs based on whatever the post variable was.

So basically onclick the selection would be passed to the controller, then the controller would return the new HTML form to be published by the JavaScript.

Hope that's not too confusing, but if you submit and example of your project might be a little easier to layout.

Comment: OK I definitely like where you're going with that, and it sounds like something I should probably try to implement in the future, but right now I'm sort of on a quick and dirty route and then going to refactor into best practices. Just getting my feet wet.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is better since it's faster and requires less HTTP requests.